# Very basic makefile linux

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am beginner of linux and having a problem about makefile
I've searched through the internet, but it didnot work for me
I use ubuntu 16.04v, and the question is about the problem on pg.96-99, programming assignment 1, book of the Operating System Concepts 9th.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int simple init(void)
{
printk(KERN INFO "Loading Module\n");
return 0;
}

void simple exit(void)
{
printk(KERN INFO "Removing Module\n");
}

module init(simple init);
module exit(simple exit);

MODULE LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
MODULE AUTHOR("SGG");
```

this is the code, and the problem says following.

> This kernel module `simple.c` is compiled using the Makefile accompanying
>   the source code with this project. To compile the module, enter the
>   following on the command line: `make`
>
> The compilation produces several files. The file `simple.ko` represents the
>   compiled kernel module. The following step illustrates inserting this module
>   into the Linux kernel.

but I have no idea how to make this to be compiled with Makefile.
I tried many times but cannot find why. maybe another code needs to be accompanied? Plz tell me.

Comment: Do you have the makefile with you? Can you post it here? Do you have kernel headers and source installed on the machine on which you are compiling this driver?

Comment: "using the Makefile accompanying the source code" this indicates that you should have a file called `Makefile`. Put this file alongside the source code, and then in the terminal in the folder write `make`

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset I got it. But what error is the OP getting? If OP can post the error it will be helpful for us to provide some insights.

Answer (score 3):

This is very basic. If you have c source you need to compile. In order to compile and link makefile is used. You can just write own makefile to compile your load module. That's said.

---

This is the very generic example of simple kernel load module that you can edit the source file names and the path.

---

Just do vi Makefile.

**makefile template**

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

save and close the file. Before that dont forget to edit your load module name.

---

**Information about the above makefile**

1. Makefile first line is called a goal definition and it defines the module to be built `hello.o`. for example `obj-m` defines a loadable module goal
2. The `$(shell uname -r)` is a useful call to return the current kernel build version
3. Then `M=$(PWD)` variable assignment tells the make command where the actual project files exist

Detailed information about [Compiling Linux Kernel Modules.](https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x181.html)

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful for your Makefile skeleton:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Taken from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html

Also, be sure to have the kernel headers installed

Answer (score 0):

If there is a file named Makefile in the path where your module is, then go to that path run command 'make' in the command line. This will compile the module code and creates simple.ko file.

To load the module into kernel use 'insmod' command(Ex : 'insmod simple.ko'). To know more type 'man insmod' enter in your command line.